# VBA File Directory Link into Outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code written (based on other posts here in SO) to insert a hyperlink to the folder that the workbook is saved in on a network drive into the body of an Email and the link does not show up in the body of the Email and I am at a loss as to why.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I do have the Microsoft Outlook Object Library checked in the References.

I have tried `hyperlink = "<a href=""" & currDir & """></a>"` and `hyperlink = "<a href=" & currDir & "></a>"` to no avail.

Below is the full code:

```
Private Sub FileToApprRev_Click()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object, MItem As Object
    Dim Subj As String, EmailAddr As String, Recipient As String
    Dim LienPos As Range, clsDate As Range, address As String, lNum As Range, Street As Range, City As Range, State As Range, ZipCode As Range, CustName As Range
    Dim strBody As String, Email As String, hyperlink As String, currDir As String


    Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSI = wb.Sheets("SavedInfo")
    Set Street = wsSI.Range("Street")
    Set City = wsSI.Range("City")
    Set State = wsSI.Range("State")
    Set ZipCode = wsSI.Range("Zip")
    Set lNum = wsSI.Range("Loan_Number")
    Set clsDate = wsSI.Range("Closing_Date")
    Set LienPos = wsSI.Range("Lien_Position")
    Set CustName = wsSI.Range("PBName")

    address = Street & ", " & City & ", " & State & " " & ZipCode

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Email = "SpongeBob@UnderTheSeaHeaven.com"
    currDir = wb.path
    hyperlink = "<a href=""" & currDir & """></a>"
    Debug.Print hyperlink

    strBody = "<p>" & "Hello , " & "<br><br>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Please complete the Appraisal Review for the file below." & "</p>" & vbNewLine & _
        hyperlink


    With MItem
        .Display
        .to = Email
        .Subject = "ATTN - Appraisal Review" & " - " & CustName & " - " & clsDate
        .HTMLBody = strBody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
        .send
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was using the incorrect structure for the file directory.

`target = "\\fsps02\users\......"`